# Parastate test tokens

Tags: blockchain

I would like to compile my solidity code on Parastate. Where can I get Parastate testnet tokens for that?
I asked in parastate telegram channels, but havn't found an answer there.
Is there any working faucet?

Answer (score 0):

Create new wallet in metamask (you will be asked to import a private key for it later) and request test tokens here: http://faucet.parastate.io/

Answer (score 0):

Previously, to get test tokens in metamask, they chose the KOVAN test network.

Answer (score 0):

use metamask wallet and choose kovan network,and go faucet http://faucet.parastate.io/ to get test token